# Unix command to replace exact match

Tags: unix, awk, sed

I want to replace exact matching string in a **tabular file**. My file somewhat look like this

```
I    1     10      100  
II   2     20      200  
III  3     30      300  
IX   9     100     1000
```

I want out put file like this

```
chrI    1     10      100  
chrII   2     20      200  
chrIII  3     30      300  
chrIX   9     100     1000
```

I have tried **sed** command with no success

```
sed -i -e 's/"III"/chrIII/g' -e 's/"II"/chrII/g' -e 's/"I"/chrI/g' filename
```

please identify the mistake. The file has large memory footprint can awk be used for the same?

Comment: is it always placed as first field? could there be values like `VI`, `XX` ?

Comment: yes it is always the first field. The values are from I to XX.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***awk*** approach:

```
awk '$1~/^[IXV]*$/{$1="chr"$1}1' OFS='\t' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

---

`file` contents after modification:

```
chrI    1   10  100
chrII   2   20  200
chrIII  3   30  300
chrIX   9   100 1000
```

---

`$1="chr"$1` - prepends each first field with `chr` substring

Comment: not always in front, just add the pattern matching `/^(I(I?(I?))|IV)[[:blank:]]/{...`

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, the OP's input shows that it is placed in "front". Added comment to the question

Comment: so assume the fact, and front was the place of maching pattern not the column (`XI` is catch by `I` and maybe not wanted). The term *exact match* is ambiguous with sample (limited).

Answer (score 2):

**sed** approach

```
sed -E -i -e 's/\b(I|II|III|IX)\b/chr\1/g' input
```

DEMO OUTPUT:

```
~$ sed  -e 's/\b\(I\|II\|III\|IX\)\b/chr\1/g' input 
chrI    1     10      100  
chrII   2     20      200  
chrIII  3     30      300  
chrIX   9     100     1000
```

Answer (score 1):

posix version (no `|`, `\b` )

```
sed -e 's/^I{1,3}[[:blank:]]/chr&/' -e 's/^IX[[:blank:]]/chr&/' input > output
```

in your

```
sed -i -e 's/"III"/chrIII/g' -e 's/"II"/chrII/g' -e 's/"I"/chrI/g' filename
```

- `"III"` search for `"III"` not `III`
- g is not a fault but not necessary (search 1st element of the string and only 1 in your sample, is it more ?)
- be careful, searching `I` will also find `II` if not delimited (here `^` for starting + a `[[:blank:]]` after)

Answer (score 0):

To put "chr" in front of first column.
Either way works well in the examples below.

```
awk '{print "chr"$0}' file
awk '{$1="chr"$1}1' file 

chrI    1     10      100  
chrII   2     20      200  
chrIII  3     30      300  
chrIX   9     100     1000
```